# Why my free quotas is all used up for seemingly nothing?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-quotas

I am trying to reason with figures and percentage in my daily quotas. Not much of progress.

I'm using GAE only for api for my android app, for saving user's items count, hence no static files or so.

Just small packets coming back and forth between them.

No crons, taskqueue, or any fancy functions at all is used. Just endpoints apis and datastore are.

So far, up until yesterday, per day, the whole requests were about 500, more or less, 18 instance hours, one-digit percentage on read/write operations.

All of a sudden, today in the morning (fyi, from east Asia), requests surged above 50,000, instance hours above 83, and ... please check attached links for snapshots below.

For instance hours, I guess it is possible, since I am using autoscaled option for them. Maybe GAE brought up a higher class of instance for better throughput. Just guessing.

But, I cannot even imagine how on earth requests became 50,000 over a night. Over 100 times! At first sight I thought I hit the jackpot, but logs tell differently. I, manually, counted how many logs for requests were came in on GAE-Logs during the past 24 hours. The count of requests were merely over 1000. (it's about twice as much more compared to yesterday's) It seems something else just drained my quotas, for something else I don't know... or for nothing...?

Also, 3 million ops of Datastore Read Operations for today makes no sense at all to me. It's three times amount of freely-allowed quotas for read operations. Until yesterday, it showed around 3% or 4%.

I am very confused. Would you please check the images links below and share your thoughts with me?

Thank you so much!

[image: imagelink -- quotas for today -- 6 hours left]

[image: imagelink for summary]

[image: imagelink for traffic]

[image: imagelink for Logs]

--------------------------------------**updated**----------------------------------------

I checked if my free quotas got reset after 6 hours for another day. But it starts where it was, like the capture below...Checked if there were massive requests from users or something. No luck. Any possibility that it might be a bug, unless there is a possible explanation?

[image: imagelink -- new quotas for next day -- 24 hours left]

Comment: You may want to go through https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dos

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You think it might have been due to Dos attack? Shouldn't it exist on GAE Logs? As I mentioned above, I manually skimmed through all my request for the particular 24 hours. But number of requests came in were about 1000. I'm not asking what is wrong with my appengine, but asking how to figure out, on my own, what is wrong. Any more suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: But you said over 50k requests. If there is a discrepancy between the request stats and the actual request logs it'd be a bug, I think. I'd ask a separate Q just for that (maybe link to this Q for context?) - but 1st check if you're looking at the logs correctly, maybe download them, etc.

Comment: Also, I did not run any security scan on my app

Comment: And yes, an unexpected sudden and massive increase in requests *could* indicate a DOS attack, especially if coming from a rather localized unknown domain. Scan through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-app-engine%5D+dos

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look into those!

Comment: I think it's a bug... According to my quotas at the moment, my app cannot handle any more requests since it's all used up for today already. (Actually, free quotas never got reset when the day passed. Gauges has been all reddish since the beginning of the day, and this smells buggy). However, requests from my clients are being handled well at the moment, as I can see them on the Log view, despite the exhausted quotas for today.. Maybe I should contact google for this issue.

Comment: I found this, potentially related: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10912

Comment: I am sure that has to do with my issue. But status of the issue is new...It's been more than 2 years since the issue was filed.

Comment: I added a comment on the issue you linked for me to share what I experienced. Although it seems not likely that anyone would pay attention all of a sudden after two years... Anyways,  Thanks to you, Dan, now I know I am not the one suffering from the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to my question:

I contacted Google Cloud Platform Support. It turned out that the dev. team could not figure out the real cause because they did not keep the logs. They presumed it is very likely to be UI bug.